# Couldn't build a gateway with Raspberry Pi 3 and LoRa Hat

Tags: raspbian, wiringpi

I'm using a Dragino Lora Hat v1.4 with SX1276 (868 MHz) for my Raspberry Pi 3B, and I'm trying to build a gateway using TheThingsNetwork(TTN). But the TTN status showed that it is **"disconnected"**.

I've followed the instructions provided in the *[user manual(PDF)](https://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/LoRa-GPS-HAT/LoRa_GPS_HAT_UserManual_v1.0.pdf)*. I've enabled the *SPI interface* and cloned and installed the necessary libraries from *[dual_chan_pkt_fwd](https://github.com/dragino/dual_chan_pkt_fwd)* and *[WiringPi](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi)*.

I've obtained my *gateway ID* and registered it as the *Gateway EUI* in TTN.
However, after I tried running the command:

```
systemctl start dual_chan_pkt_fwd
```

the *TTN status* showed that it is **"disconnected"**.

I did `systemctl status dual_chan_pkt_fwd` and `sudo journalctl -f -u dual_chan_pkt_fwd`. I got the output below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dual_chan_pkt_fwd $ sudo systemctl status dual_chan_pkt_fwd
● dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service - Lora Packet Forwarder
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service; enabled; ve>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-03-06 21:02:44 GMT; 1h 19min ago
   Main PID: 894 (dual_chan_pkt_f)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1595)
        CPU: 1.314s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service
             └─894 /home/pi/dual_chan_pkt_fwd/dual_chan_pkt_fwd

Mar 06 21:02:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Lora Packet Forwarder.
```

and

```
-- Journal begins at Tue 2023-12-05 03:07:43 GMT. --
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi dual_chan_pkt_fwd[713]: Listening at SF7 on 868.100000 Mhz.
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi dual_chan_pkt_fwd[713]: Listening at SF7 on 868.100000 Mhz.
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi dual_chan_pkt_fwd[713]: -----------------------------------
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi dual_chan_pkt_fwd[713]: stat update: 2024-03-06 21:02:39 GMT no packet received yet
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Lora Packet Forwarder.
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 06 21:02:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 06 21:02:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dual_chan_pkt_fwd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar 06 21:02:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Lora Packet Forwarder.
Mar 06 21:02:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Lora Packet Forwarder.
```

I also attempted to enable a single channel as instructed *[here](https://www.instructables.com/Use-Lora-Shield-and-RPi-to-Build-a-LoRaWAN-Gateway/)*, but this **did not change the TTN status**.
I would greatly appreciate any help you could provide. Thank you!